# resolve zeroconf-style "hostname.local" names

Tags: connection-issues, remote-control, ssh, terminal, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bash - How can I check if a computer exists on my network WITHOUT IP (i.e. by device name only)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12097/bash-how-can-i-check-if-a-computer-exists-on-my-network-without-ip-i-e-by-de)

I would like to know whether it is possible to not simply search for my avahi-enabled computer, but also to ssh to it via my ssh-android-terminal.

I'm also referring to this [question asked on Ubuntu forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4434/what-does-local-do)

From my iPad it is possible to ssh to my Ubuntu machine, but what is missing on android-side to enable this for android? Do I have to install some kind of bonjour-service or similar?

The thing is:
I sure could install a full dns-service on my Ubuntu, but I wanted to know whether I could simply use avahi/zeroconf instead. As I said above: with an iPad it us possible to connect to my Ubuntu machine by simply entering in ssh-terminal as host/IP: MyHostName.local
So my question still is: why is this not possible with android?

Sure I could use a zeroconf-browser-app that resolves the .local-adress to the actual IP. But that would be an extra step to make which is not needed on iOS... the ssh-terminal app on iOS can resolve .local itself! So do I need a terminal app that can do same? Until now I tried almost all, there aren't so many...

I hope this explains my issue a bit better.
And I don't think my question has been answered somewhere else before, as far as I can tell.

I'm not sure on how to proceed... Should I append my question to another question? Or is it just my bad explanation? :/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You might want to check [How can I check if a computer exists on my network WITHOUT IP (i.e. by device name only)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12097/16575) and, maybe, also [Q: Zeroconf mDNS on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20907/16575)

Comment: @berot3: Please make an effort to show why/how this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: "Zeroconf mDNS on Android?": Usingen HOSTS-file is not a solution. Why should I use it if I could use zeroconf? Does that mean I have to build it myself as penguinolog suggested?

Comment: "bash - How can I check if a computer exists on my network WITHOUT IP (i.e. by device name only)?": here are two workarounds suggested which appear to be a way but aren't a answer: 1: dns-daemon on my ubuntu-machine and 2: using zeroconf-discovery-browser. 1 is not an option because if zeroconf for android would work as I expect it would, than I don't see why I couldn't use zeroconf instead. 2: again: if zeroconf would be fully be implemented, it simply would work, no extra programs needed

Comment: All in all I came To the solution that android does not have zeroconf build in. So my question still remains, is there a way to add it? Or dies maybe cynanogenmod have it? Seems like I have to keep on using iPad for this purpose :)

Comment: See newer question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230644/22600